# Как сделать коллизию двух блоков на Canvas JavaScript с учетом стороны колизии

Tags: javascript, html, css, разработка-игр, html5-canvas

Делаю игру на JavaScript на Canvas, сделал передвижение персонажа и гравитацию, но никак не могу сделать правильную коллизию, такую, что она работала при слишком больших/маленьких размерах блока.
Также нужна сторона, с которой персонаж коллизит с блоком

Код для определения коллизий:

```
if (
  rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width && rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
  rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height && rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y
) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Код для определения сторон:

```
if (mob.x + mob.width >= ground.x && self.x + self.width <= ground.x) {
  if (
    (mob.y >= ground.y && mob.y <= ground.y + ground.height) ||
    (mob.y + mob.height >= ground.y && mob.y + mob.height <= ground.y + ground.height)
  ) {
    mob.x = ground.x - mob.width;
    mob.collisions.left = true;
  }
} 
// (и так для каждой)
```

Проблема в том что если персонаж 50 на 50 пикс, то при колизии с блоком 200 на 10 пикселей, боковой колизии не происходит.

Вопрос срочный, любая помощь приветствуется.

---

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Требуется уточнение: какие подходы к решению пробовались, и соотв. - что именно в попытках решения не устраивает / не получается? (существует множество способов определения столкновения фигур, и непонятно какой из них тут назван "правильным")

Comment: Могу дать ссылку на проект, чтобы вы его посмотрели. В нем работает коллизия и определение сторон, но, во-первых код получается запутанным, во-вторых при слишком маленьких\больших сторонах блока, персонаж просто проваливается

Comment: Мне (как и другим участникам, особенно тем кто впоследствии будет искать решение) интересен именно вoпрос и ответы на него, а не какой-то-там проект по ссылке... поэтому, надо добавить конкретики прямо сюда (**в вoпрос**), и желательно словесным описанием - а не заменять конкретику ссылками на внешние ресурсы которые через некоторое время могут пропасть. В первую очередь, тут очень важным моментом является используемый способ определения столкновений (его можно описать и словами, и формулами, и минимальным кодом - форма не так важна, лишь бы она была понятна).

Comment: и вот я прошу помощи в решении проблемы

Comment: Достаточно конкретики?

Comment: _«Как мне указать конктретику комментарием?»_ - зачем комментарием? Гораздо лучше будет отредактировать вoпрос, нажав под ним текстовую кнопку "[Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1320360/edit)".

Comment: Перенес в вoпрос код и условия воспроивзедения проблемы (50x50 vs 200x10) - посмотрим, достаточно ли будет такой конкретики другим участникам. _//А то чего мне не хватает для написания ответа, уже перечислил ранее (но раз трудно это добавить, то не настаиваю)._

Comment: Чтобы правильно определить сторону коллизии надо еще иметь координаты этих объектов на предыдущем шаге: знать было ли пересечение по осям до коллизии. Если пересечение по Y было, то коллизия могла быть только право-лево, и наоборот. Если пересечений не было вовсе, то коллизия произошла углами - одновременно по сторонам верх-низ и право-лево. Шаг смещения объектов не должен быть больше половины ширины или высоты одного из объектов.

Comment: У меня уже использовались предыдущие шаги, а вот за минимальный шаг спасибоъ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примечательна здесь только функция `detectCollision`. Все пояснения добавил в комментариях к этой функции. Дополнительно надо иметь в виду, что неточное обнаружение коллизии здесь возможно если дискретный шаг смещения объектов больше половины ширины или высоты одного из объектов. Но эту корректировку можно добавить в код, имея положение на предыдущем шаге.

При коллизии оба объекта меняют направление движения по соответствующей координате. Поэтому если один объект догоняет другой, то эффект выглядит неестественно. Здесь нужны дополнительные доработки.

Для того, чтобы определить каким бортами было соударение можно задать условие `if(dx > 0) rect1.sideX = 'left';`...

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('game');
const w = canvas.width = 600;
const h = canvas.height = 200;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const rect1 = {
    w : 40,
    h : 40,
    cx : 200,
    cy : 50,
    sx : 1,
    sy : -2
}

const rect2 = {
    w : 20,
    h : 60,
    cx : 400,
    cy : 120,
    sx : 2,
    sy : 1
}

draw([rect1,rect2]);

function draw(arr){
    move(arr);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    arr.forEach(r => {
        ctx.fillRect(r.cx-r.w/2,r.cy-r.h/2,r.w,r.h);
    })
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {draw(arr)});   
}

function move(arr){
    detectCollision(arr);
    arr.forEach(rect => {
        detectBorder(rect);
        rect.prevX = rect.cx;
        rect.prevY = rect.cy;
        rect.cx += rect.sx;
        rect.cy += rect.sy;
    })
}

function detectBorder(rect){
    if(rect.cx + rect.w/2 >= w || rect.cx - rect.w/2 <= 0) rect.sx = -rect.sx;
    if(rect.cy + rect.h/2 >= h || rect.cy - rect.h/2 <= 0) rect.sy = -rect.sy;
}

function detectCollision([rect1,rect2]){
    let dx = rect1.cx - rect2.cx; // Расстояние между центрами по X
    let dy = rect1.cy - rect2.cy; // Расстояние между центрами по Y
    let rx = (rect1.w + rect2.w)/2; // Минимальноe расстояние по X
    let ry = (rect1.h + rect2.h)/2; // Минимальное расстояние по Y
    
    if(Math.abs(dx) < rx && Math.abs(dy) < ry){ // если есть коллизия
        if(Math.abs(rect1.prevX - rect2.prevX) >= rx){// если по X совмещения не было, то коллизия произошла боковыми бортами
            rect1.sx = -rect1.sx;
            rect2.sx = -rect2.sx;
            // Чтобы определить стороны столкновения:
            // if(dx > 0){
            //     rect1.sideX = 'left';
            //     rect2.sideX = 'right';
            // } else {
            //     rect1.sideX = 'right';
            //     rect2.sideX = 'left';
            // }
       }
        if(Math.abs(rect1.prevY - rect2.prevY) >= ry){ // если по Y совмещения не было, то коллизия верх-низ
            rect1.sy = -rect1.sy;
            rect2.sy = -rect2.sy;
            // if(dy > 0){
            //     rect1.sideY = 'top';
            //     rect2.sideY = 'bottom';
            // } else {
            //     rect1.sideY = 'bottom';
            //     rect2.sideY = 'top';
            // }
        }
     // Если совмещение не было, то коллизия углами
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="game"></canvas>
```

Comment: _«Но эту корректировку можно добавить в код, имея положение на предыдущем шаге.»_ - или, как вариант: разделить вычисление с отрисовкой на независимые асинхр. циклы (тогда смещение объекта будет == произведению его скорости за время кадра, т.к. пропуск итераций останется только на относительно медленной отрисовке).

Comment: @yar85 я не понял. Разделить на независимые асинхронные циклы? Смещение объекта равно расстоянию, а кадр и так определяет единицу времени. Это расстояние (sx, sy) и есть скорость. И если объект на пути будет меньше этого шага, то рассматривая результат этого шага, будет непонятно откуда было начато это пересечение (ведь центры объектов могут поменяться местами). В этом случае можно изучить предыдущее положение по заданной оси и согласно им вычислить стороны "вхождения" в пересечение. Однако может быть и такое, что за один шаг оба объекта минуют друг друга если каждый из них меньше шага.

Comment: Дробить же шаг каждого кадра по идее не желательно, кадр - минимально возможная и оптимальная единица для вычисления новых координат, обработки проверки и так далее. Можно, конечно, после возникновения пересечения ретроспективно пройтись в цикле, кратном одному пикселю, например, для изучения момента вхождения, но зачем?)))

Comment: _«кадр и так определяет единицу времени»_ - только на бумаге. А в реальности, с насыщенными графикой "тяжелыми" сценами, вмешивается пропуск кадров (см. как работают асинхронные очереди микрозадач и rAF). Поэтому, проф.анимации (в продуктах где canvas-анимации стоят на непоследнем месте) часто используют разделение вычислений (быстро, стабильно) и отрисовки (медленно, возможен пропуск кадров): иногда вычисления это отдельная задача в асинхр. очереди, иногда это синхр. код срабатывающий по флагу от асинхр. задачи - не суть... важно то что **состояние не должно целиком зависеть от rAF рендера**.

Comment: Плюс, отделение вычислений позволяет оптимизации. Например, далеко не всегда нужен пересчет на **каждом** кадре (разрядив частоту вычислений можно ощутимо поднять производительность, не жертвуя кадрами). Альтернативно, можно определять пропуск итераций по аргументу коллбэка rAF и времени последнего кадра, но это лишние вычисления: иногда такое допустимо, а иногда нет... имхо, не стоит говорить что добавление вычислений это всегда хорошее решение (лучший код - тот, который не выполняется). Упрощение/сокращение работы кода - то, к чему стоит стремиться, для быстрых и плавных анимаций, имхо.

Comment: В конце концов, вообще не обязательно жестко зависеть от шагов анимации: если у нас прямолинейное движение, его легко формализовать в вектор (производная от времени, скорость-ускорение, вся матанфигня) и получать координатное значение хоть в моменте, хоть ретроспективно, хоть перспективно - и это (благодаря компиляции функций V8 и относительной простоте арифметики) адово быстрые вычисления, в отличие от ветвлений. Разве нет?

Comment: За счет чего можно распараллелить вычисления? Асинхронность то вычислительные ресурсы не прибавит если все в одном процессе происходит. WebWorkers? Майнерам на GPU скидывать?)) И с вектором мне не понятно - то есть получить функцию, описывающую траекторию движения и подставлять данные на момент отрисовки кадра? В SVG по векторному пути можно пройтись, а в canvas как? Есть же еще столкновения, как их так просто прописать сразу. Получается, нужно построить отдельную временную функцию и отдельно вести процесс rAF, с получением нужных значений в момент отрисовки кадра?

Comment: А разве я писал о распараллеливании? Прочти внимательнее...

Comment: Я вообще, исходя из того, что сама по себе асинхронность, мне кажется ничего не даст. Хорошо бы отдавать вычисления Worker'у, но боюсь, что накладные расходы на сообщения между процессами съедят всю выгоду. По сути разделенные на равные части вычисления на каждом кадре и есть оптимальное распределение ресурсов...

Comment: Насчет асинхронности хз, я не экспериментировал с воркерами в роли контроллеров анимаций... но думаю что возникнут проблемы рассинхронизации, поэтому согласен что перенос вычислений в воркер выглядит неоправданным усложнением. Выполнение вычислений синхронно / в той же очереди что и рендер но перед ним - намного проще, однопоточность в плане синхронизации является скорее плюсом чем минусом.